# Need a scroll around Raphael Canvas

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am working on a process flow diagram using Raphael JS shapes. This is dynamic; i.e, I don't know how many diagrams I am going to draw on the Raphael js canvas. It could have 10 Raphael shapes or could have hundreds, i.e, it will grow vertically.

I am facing the following issues:

1. Shapes are going out of Raphael Canvas. I want to increase/decrease the size of Canvas depending on the number of Shapes.
2. I want a scroll box around the Raphael Canvas. I don't want to use browser scroll because I also have something else on the same page and so I want to scroll just the area where Raphael shapes are, not the entire page.

Is it possible to achieve both effects?

Comment: @freakish. sorry about it. updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I gather from your question that you're wondering how to put a lot of stuff (or a big something) into a `<div>` and have scrollbars on it. To do that you just need one line of css on that div:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yJGGE/

In your case, just set the size of "scrollbox" to whatever you want the maximum size to be, and put your graphics inside it. If the graphics overflow the height of the scrollbox, scrollbars appear.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Another issue is that shapes are going out of the canvas. how to resize the canvas depend on number of shapes. i cannot hardcode canvas size because number shapes are dynamic.

Comment: To get the scrolls around the Raphael shapes, i am placing Raphael canvas in a DIV element and keeping the size of Div smaller than the canvas then using Raphael js setSize function to resize the canvas and getting the scroll around shapes. Since i have fixed height and width of the shapes, i can calculate the canvas height and width depends on the number of shapes i have drawn..